# How to destructing the array of object based on property name need to map the value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have a below specified format of the response from server , i need to map the values based on fieldnames to the formcontrol names.

```
let userForm= ths.formbuilder.group({
firstName:[],
lastName:[],userName:[],
});
```

from the service i need to destructure the below response,

Here i have getting the exact values based on property , but i need to do for each property

```
let firstName= this.form.find(
  items=>   items.fieldName === 'firstName').fieldValue

 let  getUserName = this.form.find(items=>items.userName ==='userName').value


  console.log(firstName,getUserName,'test');

}
```

service response need to map to form control model based on field name.

```
   form:any =[
      {
          fieldName: 'firstName',
          fieldValue: 'johns smith',
          isVisible: true,
          isValidationEnabled: true
      },
      {
          fieldName: 'userName',
          fieldValue: 'admins',
          isVisible: true,
          isValidationEnabled: true
      },
      {
          fieldName: 'documentType',
          fieldValue: 'Invoice',
          isVisible: true,
          isValidationEnabled: true
      }
  ];
```

can anyone provide better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just write a function to convert it to an object?

```
function formArrayToObject(formArray: {fieldName: string, fieldValue: string}[]) {
  return formArray.reduce((acc, val) => {
    return Object.assign(acc, {[val.fieldName]: val.fieldValue});
  }, {});
}
```

call that on your array and you'll have a key-value object you can access as needed. or you can call `reset` or `setValue` or `patchValue` as needed on your form:

```
this.userForm.reset(formArrayToObject(this.form))
```

Comment: when patch value with form ,it shows [object,object],` this.myForm.patchValue({
    
    
    firstName:this.formArrayToObject(this.form.firstName)
  }) ` it shows undefined attached error above

Comment: it doesn't work the way you're trying to use it. getting a specific value is a different function.. you have to use it the way I showed it...

Comment: sorry I did a mistake. working well with ur solution is there any other shortest way to map the field name response from server    to assign the fieldvalue to formcontrol declared.